# How can I pass objects to a custom django template tag? I figured out a way, but it seems hackish

Tags: django, django-templates

OK.  I am writing a system where users can "pick the winner".  I have a "matchup" table and a "picks" table.  On the matchup  webpage, I load all of the matchups for that day into the context along with all of the picks for that day.

Now, I need to display checkmark images next to the choices to allow the user to "pick" that item (just like the "best answer" check on Stack Overflow)  In order to see which checks need to be in the down (picked) state (or up state, or "won state" or "lost state"), I am creating a template tag.

Here is a relevant snippet from the template

```
  3 {% load matchup_tags %}
  4 
  5 {% for matchup in matchups %}
  6     <div class="grid_6" style="margin-top:15px; border:1px solid black;">
  7 
  8             <div class="div-status"><span class="game-status">{{matchup.status}}</span></div>
  9             <div class="opt1">
 10                 <div class="pick-home {% get_check matchup picks %}">
```

As you can see, the get_check template tag is executed in a loop.  I pass the current matchup, along with the list of picks to this template tag.

Here is my "hacked" attempt at the template tag

```
  1 from django.template import Library, Node
  2 from matchup.models import *
  3 
  4 register = Library()
  5 
  6 class PickerNode(Node):
  7     def __init__( self , matchup , picks ):
  8         self.matchup , self.picks = matchup , picks
  9         
 10     def render(self, context):
 11         p = context['picks']
 12         return p[0].pick
 13     
 14 def get_check(parser, token):
 15     bits = token.contents.split()
 16     return PickerNode( bits[1] , bits[2] )
 17 
 18 get_check = register.tag(get_check)
```

If you look at line 12 from my template tag, I am using a context variable instead of the bits[2] variable(picks which was passed in from my view as "picks").

Am I able to pass objects to my template tags?  And why would I even bother if I can just access the object in the context.

Edit:  Earlier, instead of using the context, I was doing something like
    "return self.picks.pick"
and it was throwing some "unicode does not contain property 'pick'" error

Cheers!

Comment: Yes, you can pass objects or scalar values to template tags. You can also resolve variables from the context. I don't have enough technical knowledge about Django's templating system to tell you which one is more efficient. Can anyone speak to that? I'm interested to learn more about that as well.

Answer (score 4):

You're making this harder than it needs to be. The best way to do this is to use a filter, not a tag. Filters get the value of their associated variables passed to them already:

```
@register.filter
def get_check(matchup, picks):
   # your logic here


{{ matchup|get_check:picks }}
```

Comment: +1 sometimes it's just easier to forget about the semantic of filter and use them as simple tags since they are MUCH simpler to deal with.

Answer (score 3):

I've built a 'tipping' app that does exactly what you're trying to do. It's not in a reusable state yet, but I accomplished what you're trying to do with the following:

```
@register.simple_tag
def tipped(registration, match, team):
    try:
        tip = get_tip(registration, match)
        if tip.winner == team:
            return "selected"
    except Exception,e:
        pass
    return ""
```

And the template:

```
<input type="submit" value="{{ match.home_team.display_name }}" class="button {% tipped registration match match.home_team %}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was need object directly in custom tag, not in custom filter.
This article helped me:

http://codespatter.com/2009/01/22/how-to-write-django-template-tags/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're not far off from the mark.  [This Section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/custom-template-tags/#passing-template-variables-to-the-tag) of the Django documentation demonstrates using

```
template.Variable(string_token_passed_to_tag)
```

Answer (score 0):

What do think abut this solution ?

But worked for me very very good.

template tags

```
from django import template
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
import json
register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='user_lables_set')
def user_lables_set(value):
    User = get_user_model()
    data = [e.created_at.strftime('%D') for e in User.objects.all()]
    return json.dumps(list(set(data)))
```

HTML page

```
{% extends "admin/change_list.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block extrahead %}
    {% load user_tag %}
    conole.log(JSON.parse(document.getElementById('user_lables_set').value))

{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="divider"></div>
    <input type="hidden" id="user_lables_set"  value='{{ e|user_lables_set }}'>
    {{ block.super }}
{% endblock %}
```